# Is it a right practice to use malloc for 1GB in specific to shared library?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, shared-libraries

Please help me to verify whether I am following the right coding technique/practice in specific to "Shared Library"

I have to create and deliver a 'C' "shared library" with the below requirements

1. Collect and store the data from an external device via Ethernet, using own protocol
2. Process this data
3. Provide the user application with an API which accepts the pointers to copy the processed data to.

User application will know the size of data in prior, so it can allocate that much memory in advance and pass the pointer to the API. API copies the data to the pointer. This data can go up to 1 GB.

Since I haven't wrote any shared libraries before, My first question here is about allocating 1GB memory (using malloc) in the shared library, Is it a right practice?

Second question: In the shared library, Is it a right practice to declare this memory(1GB) pointer as global, since I have multiple functions in the library to access the same memory for processing purposes? (I am taking care of the race conditions with mutex)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is "up to 1 GB", why not start with a smaller allocation and `realloc()` as needed?

Answer (score 1):

Allocating 1G of memory with malloc shouldn't be an issue in modern systems having several GBs of memory. Even if you go out of physical memory, this still will not be a performance issue until you start using that memory. Malloc simply reserves the virtual memory space, but actual memory allocation happens on the first access.
Another plus for malloc is that it doesn't initialize the memory. This will also save you some time.

Regarding the global variable. It is all about the coding style. I'd not recommend to use global variables, since they are often source of mistakes, race-conditions, hidden pitfalls.

Comment: This applies only to environments with virtual memory, in which case the memory *will* need to be zeroed the first time it is `malloc()`ed, otherwise you could read deallocated memory from another program, which would be a security disaster.

Comment: @EOF not quite ... `malloc()` doesn't do such a thing, but the OS will do on page fault before mapping a page that was previously mapped to another process. So there is indeed no performance penalty.

Comment: There can be significant performance penalties if the reserved memory can't be page-faulted in faster than it's needed.  For example, when reading from a fast device that can generate data faster than the OS can map new pages for the process doing the read.

Answer (score 0):

As a general practice, you are better off allocating large blocks of memory using operating system services directly and managing them yourself, rather than relying on whatever malloc () does behind the scenes.

Off the top a couple of reasons:

1) Malloc adds memory overhead.

2) Some malloc implementations do not handle huge chunks well.

3) Large allocations like this are more likely to fail. Using system services will usually give you more diagnostic information.

In regard to your second question, generally its not a good idea but might be in some circumstances.

You seem to imply that this is memory shared across processes in addition to being a shared library. In that case, you'd need to use an system service to create the memory block.